# Difference between two code snippets

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have written a sample `lambda` code, now I want to get some idea about a statement.

My sample code:-

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    List<ItemObject> record = new ArrayList();
    ItemObject object1 = new ItemObject();
    ItemObject object2 = new ItemObject();
    ItemObject object3 = new ItemObject();
    ItemObject object4 = new ItemObject();
    record.add(object1);
    record.add(object2);
    record.add(object3);
    record.add(object4);

    Map<String, ItemObject> stbProcessingMap = new HashMap();
    stbProcessingMap = record.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(recordingItem -> "key", recordingItem -> recordingItem, (r1,r2) -> r2));
    System.out.println(stbProcessingMap);
}
```

when I use

```
stbProcessingMap = record.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(recordingItem -> "key", recordingItem -> recordingItem, (r1,r2) -> r2));
```

Its working fine but when I use

```
stbProcessingMap = record.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(recordingItem -> "key", recordingItem -> recordingItem));
```

I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key com.modle.ItemObject@7cca494b
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1245)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.sample.App.main(App.java:30)
```

what is the difference between those two statements

Comment: did you read the javadoc of the two `toMap` methods?

Comment: It obvious! the first way use merge function to put new value but second not use it, due to this reason it throws exception.in fact in the first way it replace old value with new value with same key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example snippet uses this overload of the [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector:

```
toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
               Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
               BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

which uses a `mergeFunction` function to resolve key collisions hence the exception will not the thrown whereas the second example snippet uses this overload of the [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector:

```
toMap​(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
              Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

which will throw an exception if there is a key collision as a map cannot have duplicate keys.